# app chrashing on imageview rotation

Tags: android, imageview

Hi guys i am new on android developing and i am trying to rotate an imageview.
The problem comes when (obviously) i push the button and the app close itself
Code java:
package comad.exampleaaaa.vittoriodaadntico.bottiglia3;

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity6 extends AppCompatActivity {
public ImageView bottiglia;
public Button gira;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    gira=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_roll);
    bottiglia=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bottiglia);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main6);

}
public void rollOnClick(View v){
    RotateAnimation anim=new RotateAnimation(0,360,20,20,20,20);
    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
   anim.setDuration(700);
    bottiglia.startAnimation(anim);


}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity6, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

error log :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KRg7.jpg

Comment: plz update stacktrace..

Comment: crash -> stacktrace or close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call methods in wrong order:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    gira=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_roll); // This
    bottiglia=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bottiglia); // And this
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main6); // Should come after this
}
```

Here you search for views *before* you set content view. You should set your view, and only then search for widgets. Otherwise there is no view in which your widgets could be found, so both `gira` and `bottiglia` are `null`s:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main6);    

    gira=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_roll);
    bottiglia=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bottiglia);
}
```

Comment: this one is nice catch... but i think crashing problem is after clicking the rollOnClick and above variable he is not using

Comment: @Pavan well he's calling `bottiglia.startAnimation(anim);` so I'd say it's definitely a place for a NPE (although we don't see full stacktrace)

Comment: oh sorry ... i din't noticed that

Comment: @overclock351 if worked then you can accept answer so other will not do same mistake :)